# Jenkins with Google Cloud Source Repository

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I am trying to use Jenkins for CI/CD.
I've developed a Python flask application. I am deploying this application into Google App Engine. So far I am using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` command to deploy application to Google App Engine.

Code for this application is present in Google Cloud Source Repository.

Since the authentication to git(Google Cloud Source Repository) requires Google OAuth, I've installed [Google OAuth Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+OAuth+Plugin)

Now I am facing two issues

1. When I use "Google Service Account from metadata" Credential Kind, I am not seeing the credentials listed in "Source Code Management". 
   [image: See screenshot]
2. when I use "Google Service Account from private key", I am able to see credentials. But when I run my jenkins job I am getting below error

> FATAL: Could not call
>   com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePassword.writeObject()
>   : Failed to serialize
>   com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePasswordModule$ForRemote#credentials
>   for class
>   com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePasswordModule$ForRemote
>   ---- Debugging information ---- message             : Could not call com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePassword.writeObject()
>   cause-exception     : java.lang.RuntimeException cause-message       :
>   Failed to serialize
>   com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePasswordModule$ForRemote#credentials
>   for class
>   com.google.jenkins.plugins.source.GoogleRobotUsernamePasswordModule$ForRemote
>   ------------------------------- java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to marshal
>   org.joda.time.DateTime for security reasons; see
>   https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/     at
>   hudson.util.XStream2$BlacklistedTypesConverter.marshal(XStream2.java:543)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)

**Question**: How can I authenticate Google Cloud Source repository in Jenkins? What are the steps|plugins required to use Google Cloud Source repository in Jenkins?

Answer (score 6):

## Solution

You probably need to add a missing scope to the Compute Engine VM Instance running Jenkins that would give it access to Cloud Source Repository. You can follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) or this steps, which ever you find convenient.

1. Go to [Cloud Deployment Manager](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/dm/deployments)
2. Click on the name of the Jenkins deployment in question
3. Click on the instance name in the left info pane and it will redirect you to `VM instance details`
4. `Stop` the instance
5. Press `Edit` and set the right access scope for Cloud Source Repository

After your start the VM instance, try adding your git repository again and once you select the credentials, either "Google Service Account from metadata" or from service account, everything should work properly.

## Elaboration

I stumbled upon the "Invalid authentication credentials." issue while trying to add a Cloud Source Repository after deploying [Jenkins from Launcher](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/jenkins?q=jenkins).

In my case the reason why it happened was that during the process of deployment the [Cloud API access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) for Cloud Source Repositories **on the Compute Engine VM instance** was set to `Disabled`, which prevented any interaction from that instance even if a service account had all the necessary roles/permissions.

Here are the scopes that are reconfigured by Launcher:

```
scopes:
  - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud.useraccounts.readonly'
  - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'
  - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write'
  - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write'
  {% if enableComputeApi %}
  - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute'
  {% endif %}
  - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig'
```

Adding the following [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#sourcerepov1) to the VM instance running Jenkins was enough to fix the error:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/source.read_only
```

## Extra:

[List of scopes for Google APIs.](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

Comment: I added the required permission. But as specified in my question, when I use "Google Service Account from metadata" option, I don't see the credential listed in "Source Code Management"

Comment: I have confirmed this behavior. From [google-oauth-plugin's code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-oauth-plugin/blob/b718af8e43a3bbd152e1fccb7990e9d4863408d0/src/main/java/com/google/jenkins/plugins/credentials/oauth/GoogleRobotMetadataCredentials.java#L108) that tries to access metadata it isn't clear what is causing this. You could create an issue on Jenkins' issue tracker.

Comment: I assumed that creating service account from metadata was working because both types credentials are assigned the same name, which confused me.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the plugin to 0.6 version.
In 0.6 version, I have the same problem in Jenkins "Free-style" project.
Bit I can success to checkout in Jenkins "pipeline" project.
I just copy the "checkout syntax" in others project and replace 2 parts of the syntax to the right:

credentialsid -> replace to your right credentials id that you created Google Service Account from private key in jenkins.
url ->replace to your google source repository url